# В каких случаях создавать компоненты как классы, а в каких как функции в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В каких случаях создавать компоненты как классы, а в каких как функции ?

Comment: Убрал из вопроса лишнее.

Answer (score 0):

1. Компоненты в виде функции используют чаще всего в случаях, когда этот компонент выполняет часто повторяющееся действие. Например, в компонент-функцию можно вынести код по сортировке данных и использовать этот компонент в разных частях программы для разных данных.
2. Лучше изучайте на английском ;) Сначала будет тяжело, но через неделю с гугл транслейтом станет намного легче. Потом и вовсе без переводчика читать будете.

Всего хорошего!)